# Convert two repeated values in array into a string

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, elasticsearch-dsl

I have some old documents where a field has an array of two vales repeated, something like this:

```json
          "task" : [
            "first_task",
            "first_task"
          ],
```

I'm trying to convert this array into a string because it's the same value. I've seen the following script: [Convert array with 2 equal values to single value](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/convert-array-with-2-equal-values-to-single-value/196763) but in my case, this problem can't be fixed through logstash because it happens just with old documents stored.

I was thinking to do something like this:

```json
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "script": {
          "description": "Change task field from array to first element of this one",
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
            if (ctx['task'][0] == ctx['task'][1]) {
                ctx['task'] = ctx['task'][0];
            }
          """
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
        "_index" : "tasks",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2022-05-03T07:33:44.652Z",
          "task" : ["first_task", "first_task"]
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

The result document is the following:

```json
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "tasks",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2022-05-03T07:33:44.652Z",
          "task" : "first_task"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2022-05-11T09:08:48.150815183Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

We can see the `task` field is reassigned and we have the first element of the array as a value.

Is there a way to manipulate actual data from Elasticsearch and convert all the documents with this characteristic using DSL queries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `_update_by_query` endpoint. Here is an example:

```json
POST tasks/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": """
      if (ctx._source['task'][0] == ctx._source['task'][1]) {
          ctx._source['task'] = ctx._source['task'][0];
      }
    """,
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

You can remove the `match_all` query if you want to update all documents or you can filter documents by chaning the conditions in the query.

Keep in mind that running a script to update all documents in the index may cause some performance issues while the update process is running.